# Jquery and calendar next and previous month buttons

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am using wordpress, a plugin called The Events Calendar (great plugin btw), and I'm trying to create a little widget with a small navigational element in it.  The navigation would show the previous month, the current month, and the next month.  For example, today the navigation would show "Apr May Jun".

What should happen is when you click "Jun" it should load the events that occur in June.  I want to load these via jquery/ajax magic into a specified div.

I kinda have it working, but i have a bug and I'm not sure how to fix it. When i click one of the months that is displayed initial, it works. But then when i click another month, I'm losing my jquery function (probably due to the page not reloading completely.)

So, I'm wondering if there is a way to re-initialize the navigation so i can get more clicks.

On with the code:

My sidebar.php file contains the following code:

Some HTML

```
<div id="upcoming-events-box">
<div class="upcoming-events-block-inner">
<div class="upcoming-events-content">

    <div id="EventLoader">
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'the-events' ); ?>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And some Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {

    jQuery('#upcoming-events-months li a').click(function() {
        var toLoad = jQuery(this).attr('href')+' #EventLoader';
        jQuery('#EventLoader').hide('fast',loadContent);
        jQuery('#load').remove(); 
        jQuery('.upcoming-events-content').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
        jQuery('#load').fadeIn('normal');


    function loadContent() {
        jQuery('#EventLoader').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent);
    }

    function showNewContent() {
        jQuery('#EventLoader').show('normal',hideLoader);
    }

    function hideLoader() {
        jQuery('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
    return false;

    });
});

</script>
```

content-the-events.php which is called into the sidebar contains the following code:

```
<div id="upcoming-events-months">
 // Some php
global $post;

$current_page_URL = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];

if (isset($_GET['setmonth'])) {
$current_month = $_GET['setmonth'];
 } else {
$current_month = date('M'); // This gets the current month
}

$next_month = date('M', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($current_month)));
$prev_month = date('M', strtotime('-1 month', strtotime($current_month)));

echo "<ul>";
echo "<li><a href='http://".$current_page_URL."?setmonth=".$prev_month."'
id='".$prev_month."'>".$prev_month."</a></li>";
echo "<li>".$current_month."</li>";
echo "<li><a href='http://".$current_page_URL."?setmonth=".$next_month."'
id='".$next_month."'>".$next_month."</a></li>";
echo "</ul>";
</div>

<div id="content"></div>

<div class="upcoming-event-scroller">
<?php
$all_events = tribe_get_events(array(
'eventDisplay'=>'all',
'posts_per_page'=>-1,
'start_date'=>'01 '.$current_month.' 2012',
'end_date'=>'31 '.$current_month.' 2012'
));

foreach($all_events as $post) {
setup_postdata($post);
?>
<div class="row <?php echo (++$j % 2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd'; ?>">
<p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
<p class="event-date"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo tribe_get_start_date($post->ID, true, 'M j, Y'); ?> - <?php echo tribe_get_end_date($post->ID, true, 'M j, Y'); ?></a></p>
</div>

<?php } //endforeach ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

Maybe I've just gotten myself really confused trying to figure this out. haha. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Alot has changed since i posted this yesterday.  I am much closer to getting this to work with the exception of one problem.  I'll be sure to post my code if i can have some help working this out.  Someone else probably wants to make a widget using the The Event plugin in wordpress.

Comment: Part of the new solution is I created a basic page called events-widget. On this page it simply outputs only the events for the month with only html structure.  The format of the url looks like this: http://domain_here/events-widget/?month=May&year=2012&getAll=  However in order for my next/prev buttons to work i have to send the  month in a numeric format because the new script i have looks at the May as 05 and then to go to previous month, it just does a -1 on the number.  It does the opposite for the next button. It does a +1 on the number.

Comment: I will post the solution i came up as soon as possible. I do have it working on the website now.